# TableSorter doesn't recognize numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have these two examples, which both use the same code but different sources of tablesorter. However one of them works as the other one doesn't.

```
$("table").tablesorter();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lightheaded/x78cd/ (doesn't work)

http://jsfiddle.net/lightheaded/RYL54/ (works)

It should first sort by percent and then by users. However it doesn't recognize the second number to be a number. I have a similar situation on my site. What could be the issue? I'm using 2.14.4 min on my site as well.

Comment: why not using then the one which works?

Comment: Click the heading, both of these examples do sorting etc :/

Comment: Both fiddles working for me.. :)

Comment: Do you expect tablesorter to read your mind?

Comment: Yes, in fact. I expect the tablesorter to read minds, sentences and much more. That's what it promises :) Sorry if my description was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to a more recent version of table sorter. Recent version seems to parse out tokens from strings such as *99% coverage (12.08 million users)* and *99% coverage (10.2 million users)* and compare them one by one so strings that contain more than one number still sort out as expected (we have *10* compared with *12* in the above example).

OR: you can create a custom parser that normalizes the percentage and users; and use it:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'percentThenUsers',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        // "99% coverage (12.08 million users)" gets converted to
        // "1099 1012.08" which can then be sorted as text
        var m = s.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, " ").replace(/ +/g, " ").split(" ");
        return (+m[0] + 1000) + " " + (+m[1] + 1000);
    },
    type: 'text'
});

$(function () {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        debug: true,
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: 'percentThenUsers' }
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x78cd/10/)

Comment: Thank you! Custom parser worked. I am forced to use the old version, which doesn't have the alphanumeric sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Tablesorter attempts to detect the content of table cells automatically. In this case it is finding text and not percentage or digit values.

The first demo is using the original tablesorter which doesn't use alphanumeric sorting, so it can only sort text blocks. Check out [this updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x78cd/11/) where a row with this data is added:

```
<tr><td>10% coverage (1.0 million users)</td></tr>
```

The `10%` is placed above `100%` in ascending sorts - not what you would expect.

The second demo is using an updated version of tablesorter which does use alphanumeric sorting. It splits the text into blocks and is able to sort the content as you would expect. Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RYL54/6/) with the above row included.

If you "need" to use the original tablesorter, then use the parser provided by @SalmanA.